# Finding roots of $e^x\sin^2(x)-\cos(x)=0$ using Mathematica

Tags: roots, mathematica, transcendental-equations

$$e^x\sin^2(x)-\cos(x)=0$$

I'm trying to find 5 roots of this equation but mathematica keeps giving me back an error saying $\sin^2$ is not a well-formed equation.
Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Try typing (sin(x))^2 instead.

Comment: Thank you Zev, that got rid of the error. However It only returns 3 roots

Comment: @Zev Chonoles I think that changing $sin$^2 to $sin^2$ changes the meaning of that expression. On that particular instance the problem is regarding syntax of the software.

Comment: The original equation reads (e^x)(sin^2(x))-cos(x)=0.

Comment: @GitGud: Um, I agree, but you were the one who made that change... I was just improving your formatting.

Comment: @ZevChonoles On the equation I changed it all to $\LaTeX$, yes. But on the syntax thing below, even though I changed the appearence, the syntax was the same as the OP had typed.

Comment: Shouldn't this question be migrated somewhere as Dominic implied?

Comment: There are actually infinitely many real solutions. For $x > 0,$ simple continuity methods show that, near $x_n=2 n \pi,$ there is a solution with $x < x_n$ and another with $x > x_n.$ Not sure yet about $x < 0.$

Comment: @will jagy for $x<0$ it is the same, the roots go asymptotic to the roots of the cos for $x\to - \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mathematica you have to write

```
Exp[x] * Sin[x]^2 -Cos[x]
```

Functions are always written in capital letters, if you write `exp(x)` it will just be a variable like `x` the argument of a function is written in these `[ ]` parenthesis.

Nevertheless this is more a question for mathematica stack exchange

The equation $$ \exp(x) \cdot \sin^2(x)-\cos(x)=0$$ is equivalent to 
$$\exp(x)\cdot \sin^2(x)=\cos(x)$$ 
This equation can not be solved analytical by Mathematica.

Still you can solve it numerical, for example using

```
FindRoot[Exp[x]*Sin[x]^2 -Cos[x],{x,1}]
```

`FindRoot` uses methods like newtons-method to find the root of a function, the first argument takes the function of which you want to find the root, the second (here `{x,1}`) says that `x` is the variable and it should start searching at `x=1`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Entering the function in that way tells me that the system cannot be solved with the methods available to solve/reduce.

Comment: @joe yeah thats because of there are no analytic solutions for this one

Comment: Thank you @Dominic! I'll try this out and see if I can get the solution.

Comment: @Joe you need 5 want to see how I would say it mathematica (for numerical solutions?)

Comment: I think I got it now, Thanks Dominic. I'll post back here later if it turned out to be correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help yesterday. It turns out mathematica isn't capable of finding the exact roots of that equation. I just ended up solving them numerically.

Comment: noone is capable to find the exact roots of this equation.